# Is there a cleaner way to propagate attached data to nested templates?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

To make some 'global values' available in my template, I specify the 'options' parameter when calling tmpl:

```
var globals = { aProperty: "foo" };

$("#tcontent").tmpl(data, 
      { globals: globals }) // <-- options
.appendTo("#content");
```

I can then access properties of `globals` like this:

```
${$item.globals.aProperty}
```

Then, whenever I call another template from within the template, I need to do the following, to ensure that `globals` is once more available in the nested template:

```
{{tmpl(nestedValue, {globals: $item.globals} ) "#tnestedtemplate"}}
```

This is kind of fiddly. Is there some other cleaner mechanism for making these global values accessible in my templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're namespacing your JavaScript, you could add a `TemplateGlobals` or similar namespace:

```
Globals = {};
Globals.TemplateProperties = {};
Globals.TemplateProperties.TestProperty = "Test";
```

Now there's no need to pass around the `globals` object when you call `.tmpl`. You can access the properties directly. The obvious downside to this is that now these properties are available to all of your JS code.

```
${Globals.TemplateProperties.TestProperty}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/CqVxS/

Comment: Thanks - I thought I tried that, but perhaps I wasn't creating a properly global variable...